# How do I write a shell script called myedit which asks the user to input a file name, and then starts up an editor to edit that file

Tags: bash

How do I write a shell script called myedit which asks the user to input a file name, and then starts up vim to edit that file?

Comment: You open a file editor and write some code to do that. If you get stuck with a particular piece of code/logic, then feel free to head back to SO with that specific question. This is too broad as-is and shows 0 effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter a file name"
read file
vim $file
```

Comment: Since you're using Bash, you'd do better to `read -p "Enter a file name" file && exec vim "$file"`  (And I suggest `"${EDITOR:-vim}"` to use the user's preferred editor when that's known)

Answer (score 1):

If you are a beginner I advise you to use "Atom" for example to write your code. You just have to create a new file called "myedit.sh" with this line in header:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
```

and this little piece of code after :

```
echo "filename :"  # here, you ask the user to input a filename
read varname       # you recover the input
atom $varname &    # you open Atom to modify your file (atom is easier than vim, you just need to install it).
```

[This link can help you also](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-input.php)

Comment: That's great Marine_P as luck would have it I found a way shortly after posting this question.  I was instructed to use vim